# WPF How to read XML and create controls for each item which has a specific attribute

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq

I read so much about reading XML file and now I'm too confused with all these information about LINQ and other stuff. So I decided to ask here.

I want to read each item from the XML file with the Category "mainblocks".
And then I want to order these items by SubCategory "grassblocks".
But I don't know what to do to realize this..

I have 2 UserControls (1 for each Category).
My first UserControl should be the Category "Main Blocks".
And the SubCategorys are Expander with MaterialDesignForXAML:Cards in it which are the Items.

XAML Code:

```
<Expander Header="Grass Blocks" IsExpanded="True">
  <WrapPanel TextBlock.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}" Margin="0 8 0 16">
    <materialDesign:Card Margin="5 5 0 0" Width="330" Height="163">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="99" />
          <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="/Customizer Windows;component/Resources/placeholder_block.png" Margin="6,21,7,21" Width="64" Height="64" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">
          <TextBlock Text="Block Name" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Text="Block Description" FontStyle="Italic" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Separator Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Selected" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="16,18,33,18"/>
         <Button Content="Select" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,5,10" IsEnabled="False" />
      </Grid>
    </materialDesign:Card>
  </WrapPanel>
</Expander>
<Border Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
<Expander Header="Stone Blocks" IsExpanded="False">

</Expander>
```

This is my XAML Code and my goal is, that for each SubCategory in Category "mainblock" a Expander will be created dynamically. And in this Expander there should be a materialdesign:card created for each Item in this SubCategory dynamically.

I think LINQ will be the easiest way for this but LINQ is hard to understand (never worked with LINQ / XML before).

My XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Textures>
  <Category Name="Main Blocks">
    <SubCategory Name="Grass Blocks">
      <Texture Name="Grass Texture 1" Description="This is Grass Texture 1" IsDefault="true" IsSelected="true" TexturePath="grassblocks/grasstexture1.png" />
      <Texture Name="Grass Texture 2" Description="This is Grass Texture 2" IsDefault="false" IsSelected="false" TexturePath="grassblocks/grasstexture2.png" />
    </SubCategory>
    <SubCategory Name="Stone Blocks">
      <Texture Name="Stone Texture 1" Description="This is Stone Texture 1" IsDefault="true" IsSelected="true" TexturePath="stoneblocks/stonetexture1.png" />
      <Texture Name="Stone Texture 2" Description="This is Stone Texture 2" IsDefault="false" IsSelected="false" TexturePath="stoneblocks/stonetexture2.png" />
    </SubCategory>
  </Category>
  <Category Name="Ore Blocks">

  </Category>
</Textures>
```

This is all what I have for now.
I started a bit with LINQ but deleted it because it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: You need to make the xml file a little better so the default and alternative can be grouped together.  The default and alternative should both have the same category and subcategory.

Comment: Okay I edited my XML Code. But How I read this XML and creating the control for each Texture? Can u post a link with a perfect tutorial or something like that?